# How to create an gradient button with colored shadow

Tags: button, dart, flutter

I'm kind of noobie in Flutter and I'm trying to learn it for the moment by creating different UI styles for whatever applications. But I encounter a problem in terms of designing a button.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO:**

[image]

**WHAT I TRIED:**

- Using a [GradientButton](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gradient_widgets):

  - *I can't change the rounded corners to not be that rounded.*
  - *I can't change the size of the button dynamically based on the size of text*
  - *I can't change the shadow of the box*
- Using a **RaisedButton** in combination with a **Container**:

  - *If I will tap the button is going to show a gray box which was clicked on, but this box is not going to have the same size or shape with the box, so it's going to look weird.*
- Using an **InkWell** in combination with a **Container**:

  - I'm not quite sure but I can't do the click animation with that, is like I'm pressing on nothing, even those the action is happening.

If you do have any idea how can I archive this button please let me know, for me at the moment at least is the most complicated button I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Container` to custom button gradient and add `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` to `onTap` handle action.
`GestureDetector` will have no effect. `InkWell` will have effect.

Answer (score -1):

see the source code at github
https://github.com/bluemix/Gradient-Widgets/blob/master/lib/src/gradient_button.dart

Comment: Yeh sure... That's helped a lot, is not like I did it already this... :/